# Появляется navbar только в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не могу понять почему навбар не показывается (без бургера) в ширине более 578п. Помагити пж.
ппс Подправьте меня если я код неправильно где то пишу.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collase" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
        <div class="p-4">
          <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Компания</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Продукция</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Услуги</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Объекты</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Техподдержка</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: дивы с class="container" добавлены, это кусок кода

Comment: <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto collapsed" style="display:block;" ...

Comment: @Konst Это так не работает.

Comment: проверьте правильность классов, вот например: navbar-collase

Comment: @Konst а вот так работает))) Спасибо вам большое)